# How to update a Prisma model that has a relation "one-to-many" in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, crud, prisma

I have this two prisma models in nestjs:

```
model DevInformations {
  userId      Int      @unique
  relatedUser User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  name        String
  lastName    String
  dateOfBirth DateTime
  telNumber   String
  city        String
  zip         String
  country     String
  resume      String?
  links       Links[]
}
```

and

```
model Links {
  id          Int             @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  userId      Int
  relatedUser DevInformations @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId])
  name        String
  link        String
}
```

I have no problem with the create method but I cannot find a way to update **the links field** without typescript yelling at me or having nestjs errors.

I don't understand the steps to update this specific field.

For example here is my code

```
const devInfo = await this.prisma.devInformations.update({
      where: {
        userId,
      },
      data: {
        ...rest,
        links: {
          create: [...dto.links],
        },
      },
      include: {
        links: true,
      },
    });
```

And my DTO:

```
export class UpdateDevInfosDTO {
  @IsNumber()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userId: number;

  ....All the fields,

  @IsArray()
  links: ILinkInput[];
}

export interface ILinkInput {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  link: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of errors are you getting? I managed to replicate the model with no errors, but without context of what exactly you are trying to do with links, there is little help.

***EDIT:**
I see you are trying to change links, but your code specifically tries to change `DevInformations`.

Try to change links, but specify related DevInformations instead.

Wrote this code that **somewhat** resembles what you're trying to do.

```
// Find existing links that you want to update
const existingLinks = await this.prisma.links.findMany({
        where: {
          name: { // Can change to look for devInformations instead
            in: links.map((link) => link.name),
          },
        },
      });
    
// Map their names
const existingLinkNames = existingLinks.map((link) => link.name);
const linksToCreate = links.filter(
        (link) => !existingLinkNames.includes(link.name)
      );
const linksToUpdate = links.filter((hub) =>
        existingLinkNames.includes(link.name)
      );
const createdLinks = await this.prisma.links.createMany({
        data: linksToCreate.map((link) => ({
          name: link.name,
          // Connect with devInformations
          connect: {
              userId: devInfo.userId
          }
        })),
      });

// Perform same operations to match your use case
const updatedLinks = await this.prisma.links.updateMany({
        where: {
          name: {
            in: linksToUpdate.map((link) => link.name),
          },
        },
        data: {
          description: {
            set: linksToUpdate.map((link) => link.description),
          },
        },
      });
```

Comment: My error is: "Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)". It just that I don't know how to handle the update 'strategy' I would say... I'll update my post with more info

Comment: Also, you can provide a minimum example on GitHub so we could hop in and try to solve your case